# grunt and javascript partial file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify, partial

In my project I have directory with partials of javascript files.
In this directory I have files like:
_register.js, _user.js, _cart.js, _common.js
and I wanna make some full files

> **user.js** must have _user.js, _common.js, _register.js
>
> **product.js** must have _user.js, _common.js, _cart.js

and this should be compiled to 2 directories
**dev/** and **prod/**
in dev I must have normal javascript and in prod I must have minified versions, how to get it with grunt?

Comment: Choose a module system - I recommend webpack or requirejs. Then see the many grunt tasks and tutorials for doing exactly that ^

Comment: Agree with @DominicTobias. You might want to use a module system and an associated bundle tool. I currently use browserify (and there is a nice grunt plugin for it grunt-browserify)